# How I can add more data to Laravel's auth()->user() object + it's relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My `user` model has foreign key reference called `person_id` that refers to a single `person` in my `people` table.

[image]

When I die & dump the authenticated user (`dd(auth()->user())`) I get:

```
{"id":1,"email":"foo@bar.baz","is_enabled":1,"person_id":3,"created_at":"2017-12-12 10:04:55","updated_at":"2017-12-12 10:04:55","deleted_at":null}
```

I can access person by calling `auth()->user()->person` however it's a raw model. Person's Presenter is not applied to it hence I can't call presenter methods on auth user's person because I don't know where to call my presenter.

Where is the best place to tune up `auth()->user` object and it's relationships so I can apply specific patterns on them?

Thanks,
Laravel `5.5.21`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`load()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) method:

```
auth()->user()->load('relationship');
```

Comment: Hey Alexey, your solution works however I have to manually call it in every controller's method where I want to use it. Where's the best place to put it so the effect will be global. Base abstract controller? Any better place?

Comment: @slick you can do this in middleware.

Comment: Or use `$appends = ['relationship']` in your model. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Answer (score 5):

You can use [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#global-scopes):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function person()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Person::class);
    }

    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('withPerson', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->with(['person']);
        });
    }
}
```